# Delay via GCD vs. sleep()

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have the method in which I need to make a 5 sec delay every time I call it. Firstly I make it with `sleep(5);` - it worked excellent but I believe - it's not obj-c way, so I tried to write it with GCD help. The first call of this procedure make a delay about 5 sec, but other calls in this queue are going one after one without delay. How to solve this problem?

```
- (void) buyItemAtUUID:(NSString*)UUID
{
    dispatch_barrier_async(dataManagerQueue, ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dataManagerQueue, ^(void){
            NSInteger path = [self indexFromObjectUUID:UUID];
            if (path != NSNotFound)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *item = [[_items objectAtIndex:path] mutableCopy];
                NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[item objectForKey:@"Quantity"] floatValue] - 1.0];
             }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Off topic, but why do you use `mutableCopy` given `objectForKey:` is an `NSDictionary` method?

Comment: is your `dataManagerQueue` a custom Concurrent queue, or a serial queue?

Comment: @Abizern dataManagerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Data Manager", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

Comment: @trojanfoe this is just an example - I cut the lines from it to make it shorter

Answer (score 2):

> The first call of this procedure make a delay about 5 sec, but other
>   calls in this queue are going one after one without delay.

That's usually desired behavior. The reason you shouldn't call `sleep()` is that it'll block the thread, preventing anything else in that thread from happening. If you block the main thread, your device will appear to freeze, which isn't a very nice user experience.

GCD provides a nice `dispatch_group_wait()` function that lets you make one set of tasks wait for some other group to finish. Take a look at [*Waiting on Groups of Queued Tasks*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) for an example.

Comment: OK, I can execute dispatch_group_wait() but how can I write the delay function correctly?

Comment: What's the 5-second delay for? Are you trying to allow enough time for some network operation to complete?

Comment: Just the delay, this is the test task to get job: "The delay between pressing the button "Buy" and executing the task should be 5 seconds". It's just an artificial delay to show that multithreading works fine for readwrite to the file.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_barrier_async` only stops blocks added to the concurrent queue **after** this block from running. The blocks that were already queued are not prevented from running.